# не запускается Apache

Tags: apache

пытаюсь запустить apache:
systemctl start httpd

но получаю ошибку

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-01-29 09:23:09 MSK; 5min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 24116 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 24115 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 24115 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru httpd[24115]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru httpd[24115]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru kill[24116]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 29 09:23:09 example.vds.ru systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

подскажите как можно решить данную проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

Это проблема связанна с тем, что какая то программа или сервис занимает порт апача
 1. Попробуйте выключить скайп(самое простое)
 2. Проверьте используемые порты
 3. Смените порт в апаче на свободный порт, который не занят другим приложением или сервисом

Comment: попробую пройтись по п2 и п3 . Скайпа  нет т.к сервер удаленный.